# Is there any mechanism make Metro app crash automatically on Win8？

Tags: crash, microsoft-metro

We are developing a new Windows Store App with C# now. It is strange that the app crashed occasionally but haven't given any infomation . Now we deploy an IDE on the Surface and use it to run our code. The app crashed as the same, and the IDE didn't give any information. 
So we want to know if Win8 system will kill app at some special cases ?

By the way, our all code blocks had using try-catch and we use async and await very carefully.
Most crash happend when the App access some network service.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you use `async void`?

Comment: Well,we know that exceptions always won't be captured when they happend in an async void funciton. So we just try to avoid using async void function if it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every body!
I think there is not any systematic mechanism to make our app crash. But some bugs on the system really influence the quality of the software.
As our app, it crashed many times when using grouped GridView and when the pages enabled NavigationCachemode. After removing these features, it crashed less.